# Getting OptionalDataException because of primitive int value , but how to avoid it in JAVA

Tags: java, serialization, io, datainputstream

My Code-

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;

public class ObjectStreamExample {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Person person = new Person();
        person.setFirstName("Abhishek");
        person.setLastName("Choudhary");
        person.setAge(25);
        person.setHouseNum(256);
        ObjectOutputStream stream = null;
        try {
            stream = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File("Serialize.txt")));
            stream.writeUTF(person.toString());
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally{
            if(stream != null)
                try {
                    stream.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }

        ObjectInputStream input = null;

        try {
            input = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(new File("Serialize.txt")));

            Person person2 = (Person) input.readObject();
            System.out.println(person2.getFirstName());
            System.out.println(person2.getLastName());
            System.out.println(person2.getAge());
            System.out.println(person2.getHouseNum());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally{
            if(input != null)
                try {
                    input.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }


    }

}
```

and one Person bean file.

I am getting exception

> java.io.OptionalDataException     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)  at
>   com.practise.interview.nio.ObjectStreamExample.main(ObjectStreamExample.java:62)

This is getting raised because I think -

> An attempt was made to read an object when the next element in the
>   stream is primitive data. In this case, the OptionalDataException's
>   length field is set to the number of bytes of primitive data
>   immediately readable from the stream, and the eof field is set to
>   false.

But how to avoid it as I know I set a  primitive value, so way to avoid.?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are writing a `String` and try to read a `Person`. That's not how serialization works. In the context of serialization, an UTF string is considered primitive data, because it does not contain object information (class name, attributes etc.), but only the string data.

Write out the `person` object itself, if you want to read a `Person` afterwards:

```
stream.writeObject(person);
```

**Addendum:** If writing a `String` would behave like with any other `Object`, you would get a `ClassCastException` instead, because the `String` could not be cast to `Person`. In any case, the mismatch between what you write and what you read is causing the error you got.

Comment: "*In the context of serialization, an UTF string is considered primitive data*" - Source?

Comment: A `String` is not serialized as any other Object containing a `char[]`, but is handled specially by the framework. -- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/platform/serialization/spec/output.html#a933 - "9. If the object is a java.lang.String, the string is written as length information followed by the contents of the string encoded in modified UTF-8." -- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/platform/serialization/spec/serial-arch.html#a4176 - "Primitive data types are written to the stream with the methods in the DataOutput interface, such as writeInt, writeFloat, or writeUTF."

Answer (score 1):

accroding to specification

Exception indicating the failure of an object read operation due to unread primitive data, or the end of data belonging to a serialized object in the stream. This exception may be thrown in two cases:

- An attempt was made to read an object when the next element in the
  stream is primitive data. In this case, the OptionalDataException's
  length field is set to the number of bytes of primitive data
  immediately readable from the stream, and the eof field is set to
  false.
- An attempt was made to read past the end of data consumable by a
  class-defined readObject or readExternal method. In this case, the
  OptionalDataException's eof field is set to true, and the length
  field is set to 0.

  stream.writeUTF(person.toString()); // Problem is here

Here you are write as UTF and in other end You are reading as a Person Object.
You should change it -

```
stream.writeObject(person);
```